# Why does char type variable still compile if it takes more than 1 character?

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ char type variable and what i learn is that sizeof(char) = 1 which means it can only hold 1 ASCII character. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and Here's the strange behavior i've found:

```
char x = 'abcd';
std::cout << x;   //it prints 'd', the last letter.
char y = 'dcba';
std::cout << y;   //it prints 'a', the last letter.
```

surprisingly, it still compile and give the output as commented above. What is Visual Studio doing here? what's the logic behind outputting the last character?

However, when i do:

```
char x = 'abcde';
```

Visual Studio has warn me "too many characters in character constant", and **cannot compile at all!** Again, what's the logic here? If char cannot take more than 1 character, why does it still accept a input of length 1 to 4, but not anything more than 4?

[VS warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR9r4.png)

Comment: There is a difference between the `char` on the left of the assignment, and the "multicharacter literal" on the right, which could be assigned to a `wchar_t` for example. It's a bit like assigning a `double` into a `float`; the value will be truncated.

Comment: @hobbs, I've seen that question, not exactly sir

Comment: @Inian That is not correct, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal

Comment: As explained in the duplicate a multi-character literal is an `int`. As an `int` in visual studio is 4 bytes if you enter more than 4 characters visual studio issues a warning.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, so the first question on why it truncated and output the last letter, is also something by default?

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri: Yes I pasted the wrong text, a few lines above (from C++ PL 4th edition) I see "It is possible to enclose more than one character in a character literal, for example,`'ab'`. Such
uses are archaic, implementation-dependent, and best avoided. The type of such a multicharacter literal is `int`.

Comment: you're assigning an `int` to a `char`, that will truncate to the least significant byte in the `int`